# How to create a Json file in google storage from DataFrame?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have the following code (Python 2.7):

```
import pandas as pd
....
pd.DataFrame(response2.json())['results'].to_json('orders.json', orient='records')
```

This saves a `orders.json` file in my local project.
I want the file to be written to my Bucket on Google Storage and not to my local machine.

Is it possible to generate the file directly to the storage or must I create it locally and then upload it?

I know it should be something like:

```
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("MyTestBucket")
blob = bucket.blob("folderName/" + blob?!)
blob.upload_from_filename("orders.json")  # Or something with writing the DataFrame?
```

Can someone help with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found using datalab.storage is more convenient to write data to Google Cloud Storage.

```
import datalab.storage as storage
import pandas as pd

# Define sample dataframe to write
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[{1,'product1','description1'},{2,'product2','description2'}],columns=['id','name','description'])

# Define your bucket and write to GCS
storage.Bucket('{your-bucket-name}').item('{folder}/{your-file}.json').write_to(df.to_json(),'text/json')
```

Comment: I'll try it. Would this also create the {folder} if it doesn't exists? does it also support {folder}/{sub-folder}/{your-file}.json  ?

Comment: @jack yes it will create the folder automatically.